# Data overwrite google sheet - Jupyter connection

Tags: api, google-sheets, jupyter-notebook

I created a connection between my Jupyter notebook and google sheet.
My idea was to create a log so everytime I run the notebook it would update my google sheet with the new data but I don`t want to overwrite the existing data, I want to add.  I tried many solutions but it didn`t work

Currently my code is:

```
## Connect to our service account
scope =["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('jupyter-and-gsheet-303208-63903bea8f5d.json', scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

spreadsheet_key = '1RbPnMdJ-EcJHbly280vrJxc8UvqwiBPkUTFLyo4efEA'

from df2gspread import df2gspread as d2g
wks_name = 'Data04'
d2g.upload(df_apn1, spreadsheet_key, wks_name, credentials=credentials)
```

It works perfectly but always overwriting the existing data.
Does anybody know how I can add instead of replace?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**df2gspread** document for [upload()](https://df2gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#usage) indicates that

> if spreadsheet already exists, all data of provided worksheet(or first as default) will be replaced with data of given DataFrame, make sure that this is what you need!.

Another workaround is to convert your dataframe to a list and use gspread [append_rows](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Worksheet.append_rows).

Example:

**Code:**

```
import gspread
import pandas as pd
gc = gspread.service_account()
sh = gc.open_by_key("someid").sheet1
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Bea', 'Andrew', 'Mike'], 'Age': [20, 19, 23]})
values = df.values.tolist()
sh.append_rows(values)
```

**Before append:**

[image]

**After append:**

[image]

**You may also check the following libraries:**

- [gspread-pandas](https://github.com/aiguofer/gspread-pandas)
- [gspread-dataframe](https://github.com/robin900/gspread-dataframe)

**Reference:**

- [gspread](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: I used the append_rows workaround and it worked. Thank you